# Cannot get rid of default manifest react js in Azure Web Static App

Tags: reactjs, azure

I built a reactjs app in Azure Web Static App.

But the thing is I cannot change the app manifest when publish to Azure, even I already altered values of manifest at the project.

In network:
[image: network]

In my project:
[image: myproject]

Seem like Azure Static Web App always sets a default manifest json to react js app.

Is there a way to resolve this?

Thanks everyone.

Updated:
since I linked to the wrong manifest. Azure Web Static App does use your manifest. If you edit it, Azure web will also follow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

since I linked to the wrong manifest.
Azure Web Static App does use your manifest.
If you edit it, Azure web will also follow. Thanks.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32101536)